# docker restart does not work after raspberry host crash

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi, restart

I am following this [tutorial](https://blog.alexellis.io/live-stream-with-docker/) to create a live streaming service from my raspberry's webcam.

As I want to guarantee the uptime and make sure the stream re-starts when needed, I use the `--restart=always` option.

```
# I masked my stream key with XXX...
docker run --restart=always --privileged --name cam -d alexellis2/streaming:17-5-2017 XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX
```

The restart works perfectly fine if I restart my raspberry with `sudo reboot`, however it does not work on a host crash or "hard reset" (cut & restore the electricity).

Is there a way to make sure the container also gets restarted when the host crashes?

Comment: Find out what happened? Looking for an answer as well

Comment: No, nothing. I wrote myself a cron script that checks every minute of the container is running and starts it if not